# jsonfield violates not-null constraints and filetype is not unsupported

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-testing, factory-boy

I Have a model field

```
field_name = JSONField(editable=False)
```

from django admin I can't save it.

If I give json format data in the time of test with factory boy

```
field_name = factory.build(dict, FACTORY_CLASS=NewsProviderFactory)
```

it shows this error

```
'InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 10 - probably unsupported type'
```

Comment: what all different json formats did you try?

Comment: I edit this, please read one more time